# прочитать числовой ряд из xls

Tags: matlab, xls

по анализу данных в MATLAB нужно изучить временной ряд. Как прочитать временной ряд  из файла xls? Данные вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй функцию xlsread, её описание лежит здесь:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html